# C# Deserializing JSON with object inside list of objects - but cant acces it

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net

I have a program that needs to recieve a JSON object, which contains an object with a list of objects and an object inside each object in the list.

Theres no problem accessing the objects inside the "OuterGameResponse", but the Usernames are Null. I access the Highscores lige this:

```html
string json = @"{""Games"":[{""Highscore"":35,""Coinsgained"":35,""Starttime"":""2021-12-08T12:30:50.543766"",""User"":{""Username"":""Smorgaard""}},{""Highscore"":35,""Coinsgained"":0,""Starttime"":""2021-12-08T13:09:00.384853"",""User"":{""Username"":""Smorgaard""}},{""Highscore"":25,""Coinsgained"":25,""Starttime"":""2021-12-08T11:14:16.125606"",""User"":{""Username"":""Smorgaard""}},{""Highscore"":10,""Coinsgained"":10,""Starttime"":""2021-12-08T12:49:28.987071"",""User"":{""Username"":""Smorgaard""}},{""Highscore"":0,""Coinsgained"":0,""Starttime"":""2021-12-08T12:48:57.309838"",""User"":{""Username"":""Smorgaard""}}],""Message"":""OK"",""Code"":200}";

            GamesResponse _gr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GamesResponse>(json);

            Console.WriteLine(_gr.Games[0].Highscore);
```

But can't do something like this:

```html
Console.WriteLine(_gr.Games[0].User.Username);
```

Is there any way to do this, without the objects inside the list being nulls?

Below is the classes i want to deserialize the JSON into.

```html
[Serializable]
public class GamesResponse
{
    public List<OuterGamesResponse> Games;

    public string Message;
    public int Code;
}

[Serializable]
public class OuterGamesResponse
{
    public int Coinsgained;
    public int Highscore;
    public DateTime Starttime;
    public InnerGamesResponse User;
}

[Serializable]
public class InnerGamesResponse
{
    public string Username;
}
```

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GVWY7H).

Comment: Tested in LINQPad, username property is properly populated. Is the code in the question your **actual** code?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen username _field_.

Comment: It was still properly populated though. I copied and pasted the code from the question, I get a username written with that console.writeline statement, and I can see all fields have been populated.

Comment: Yes, but the distinction is relevant when discussing reflection-based APIs.

Comment: I understand that but might be irrelevant to the question here since the code actually works as expected. As such, there has to be something else wrong rather than the code that has been posted.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you're using Newtonsoft, and not System.Text.Json? If you're using STJ, then you'd need to make them properties, not fields.. (The code posted is definitely Newtonsoft flavored, but your complaint is reproducible if using STJ)

Comment: @CaiusJard `JsonConvert` is a JSON.Net type, not System.Text.Json. Furthermore, OP claims `_gr.Games[0].Highscore` is not null, and `Games` / `Highscore` are also fields.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If an answer solves your problem mark it as an acceptable answer. If it helps you give it an upvote. If the answer is offtopic or doesn’t help at all, downvote or add a comment. See also [stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do this

At the risk that you're not actually using Newtonsoft, and you've just stuck the first two lines in as a test harness for our benefit, but are instead using e.g. System.Text.Json (perhaps implicitly via some ReadAsJsonAsync web extension call) with its default settings you should note that we typically make our classes that we de/ser using *properties*, rather than fields, so like:

```
public class GamesResponse
{
    public List<OuterGamesResponse> Games {get;set;}

    public string Message {get;set;}
    public int Code {get;set;}
}
```

The `{get;set;}` is the minimum code necessary to turn a field into a property.

Newtonsoft isn't as fussy, and will de/ser properties or fields, but System.Text.Json for example, will not de/ser fields unless it's a recent version and the fields have been marked with `[JsonInclude]` or you've specified that they should be included in the serializer options

Answer (score 0):

In the actual code i recieve the JSON data via Websocketshap as shown below - could the problem occur here in any way?

```
private GamesResponse _gr;

public LeaderboardManager()
{
    WebSocketClient.OnMessageEvent += this.OnMessage;
}

void OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
{
    _dataRecieved = true;

    _gr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GamesResponse>e.Data);
}
```

Comment: I don't personally see how it could, but if you're still puzzled and want to bundle the entire project up into a zip file and host it somewhere (github is common, or you can even put it inside a GIF using [this technique](https://www.howtogeek.com/119365/how-to-hide-zip-files-inside-a-picture-without-any-extra-software/) and add it to your question as an image, so that we can have a go at reproducing the problem with your exact code, then I'd be happy to take a look at it

Comment: @CaiusJard your responses was of huge help. I found the problem to occur serverside, as the first seeded username was NULL, which crashed the application in the beginning every time.